# What is your best practice way to make a MVC Dojo application in the browser?

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

I have recently made a custom MVC Dojo application inside Adobe Air, which has worked alright, but I am not entirely satisfied with my own improvised MVC solution.

This question is only concerned with the browser technology, and should not require any fixed server side technology other than say a JSON rest service.

There seems to be a movement to clean MVC frameworks in javascript with new solutions emerging every day such as Backbone, spine, javascriptmvc, and so on. But for Dojo I have not found a real client side structure to follow.

I know for Dojo, there is cujo, but I have no experience implementing Cujo and would be interested to hear other people's experiences.

So what is your best practice solution for implementing MVC in Dojo for a complex client side application?

Comment: the Dojo developers is currently in very active discussions regarding adding binding support to Dojo/Dijit and a sophisticated MVC layer on top.  Several prototypes are being evaluated.  I encourage you to write up a description of your current solution and send it to the Dojo forums, so that we can also take your experiences into the whole picture!

Comment: check out this link: http://www.mingleplace.com/test/bindingtest.html for a prototype of low-level binding support (which enables MVC-style binding of view to a controller/view-model).

Comment: @Stephen, I will join the forums on Dojo and see what kinds of solutions are being developed. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: you should search the Dojo Developer's Mailing List for past discussions on MVC and binding.  I believe there were a whole flood of messages during the past month or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a comprehensive MVC solution, but you may want to check out a small [demo app](https://github.com/rmurphey/dojo-demo) that I put together that shows how to lay out the basics of a Dojo application, and which includes a router component for handling application-wide state management.

Comment: Thank you for the quality example, it is very integrated with dojo and the inclusion of a router component is useful.